# How to migrate only categories data to Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, category, migration

After migration, I notice that I can't save **categories** in the backend. After all the diagnosis I found no solution.

I want to migrate only the **categories data**, Is it possible?

( Without clear all the store or running again the entire migration )

Comment: which tool you use for migration ?

Comment: I'm using data migration tool, link to repo https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool

Comment: What error are you finding in backend while saving categories?

Comment: Categories don't apply the changes. After I save category it say 'category saved' but I can't see the category data anymore. I found that the 'attribute_set_id' changed from 45 to 3 with no reason.